# PHP/MYSQL GROUP BY to Array based on grouping

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have a table like this:

```
 ID   Name  Type
 1    Adam    A
 2    Sam     B
 3    James   A
 4    Dave    C
 5    Vick    C
```

And I'd like to get them into an array format like this in **PHP**:

```
people['A'] == {Adam, James}
people['B'] == {Sam}
people['C'] == {Dave, Vick}
```

How do I manipulate the GROUP BY function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where you want `group_concat()`:

```
select type, group_concat(name)
from t
group by type
```

Comment: so would each row be returning an array based on this query?

Comment: @JamesGu . . . You need to load the comma delimited list into an array in php.  Your question is tagged with SQL, so this is the SQL component.  There are no "arrays" in SQL; a comma delimited list is how you would encode this information.